# Hexadecimal String to binary PDF file

Tags: php, pdf, hex

I have a hexadecimal value that is a PDF that I am getting from a web service that I am trying to save locally using PHP. The below is a snippet of the value.

I have tried to achieve this using pack in PHP either receive an error that "x" is not valid or the pdf will not save correctly. It will be empty or says error opening.

```
   Partial Value is:     "0x255044462D312E340A0A322030206F626A0A3C3C2F5479"
```

I have tried the following unsuccessfully after searching google for some time:

```
   $pack = pack("h*", $string);

    file_put_contents('my.pdf', $pack);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
    echo $pack;
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly? I realize this is not the entire PDF but I cant put entire online.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Remove `0x`using `str_replace`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried that as well.. I then get a file to download but it cannot open it.

Comment: I know what's going on, it's not `pack('h*',$string)` it's `pack('H*',$string)`, with uppercase.

Comment: Changed to below. Still says cannot be opened may be damaged. This same one opens in an application fine.. So I know it is valid.

    $string = str_replace("x", "", $string);

    $pack = pack("H*", $string);

    file_put_contents('my.pdf', $pack);
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="my.pdf"');
    echo $pack;

Comment: It's `str_replace("0x", "", $string);` :P

Comment: Ha.. yeah I tried that one too.. I am at a lost at this point

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30367/discussion-between-ultimateprogrammer-br-and-nikon0266)

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same issue! And not only with PDF documents, also with DOC and others.