# Converting hex string to binary file makes it corrupt and unable to open

Tags: php, pdf, binary, hex, decoding

When converting the hexadecimal value, a PDF file, the file is corrupted.
This is the partial hex content of a simple pdf file I want to convert:

```
0x255044462D312E370D0A25B5B5B5B50D0A312030206F626A0D0A3C3C2F547970652F436174
```

Full string: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5tpgyhex/), [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/RpZmHpzW)

This question is a continuation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67998821/create-file-system-file-from-file-stored-in-microsoft-sql-database/67999388#67999388) question, where I said that I have to do a data migration between two programs that handle files differently.
The source program stores the files hex encoded in the database.

I could successfully extract and convert text files to binary files with the following code:

```php
file_put_contents(
    'document.pdf', 
    hex2bin(str_replace('0x', '', $hexPdfString))
);
```

But when I run this function on a pdf file or other binary file, it is corrupted.
My question is pretty much the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681002/hexadecimal-string-to-binary-pdf-file) but discussion over there was unfortunately discontinued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of hex decoding your string is corrupted **because your string is incomplete**, it only contains the first 65535 characters. After hex decoding one can see that the PDF is cut off inside a metadata stream:

```cos
20 0 obj
<</Type/Metadata/Subtype/XML/Length 3064>>
stream
<?xpacket begin="ï»¿" id="W5M0MpCehiHzreSzNTczkc9d"?><x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="3.1-701">
<rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""  xmlns:pdf="http://ns.adobe.com/pdf/1.3/">
<pdf:Producer>MicrosoftÂ® Word 2019</pdf:Producer></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">
<dc:creator><rdf:Seq><rdf:li>Samuel Gfeller</rdf:li></rdf:Seq></dc:creator></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""  xmlns:xmp="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/">
<xmp:CreatorTool>MicrosoftÂ® Word 2019</xmp:CreatorTool><xmp:CreateDate>2021-06-17T13:00:19+02:00</xmp:CreateDate><xmp:ModifyDate>2021-06-17T13:00:19+02:00</xmp:ModifyDate></rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about=""  xmlns:xmpMM="http://ns.adobe.com/xap/1.0/mm/">
<xmpMM:DocumentID>uuid:C29344F5-3E78-414A-B4E3-775A853B1A0C</xmpMM:DocumentID><xmpMM:InstanceID>uuid:C29344F5-3E78-414A-B4E3-775A853B1A0C</xmpMM:InstanceID></rdf:Description>
```

The length 65535 of course is special, it's 0xFFFF. Apparently some mechanism you used in retrieving that string could not handle strings longer than 65535 characters. Thus, you have to investigate the source of that string.

Considering [the question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67998821/1729265) you consider this question a continuation of, I'd assume that either the field in the MS SQL database you retrieve the data from is limited to 65535 bytes or your database value retrieval code cuts it down.

In the former case there'd be nothing you can do, the database contents simply would be incomplete. In the latter case you'd simply have to enable your database access code to handle long strings.

Comment: Hey, I have the same issue again, but I can't share the binary code publicly. Would you mind giving me a way (discord, email or other) to send you the binary PDF content?

Comment: I sent an email with a few examples.

Comment: I cannot recognize any PDF structure in the example hex strings in your mail. Nor can I recognize the structure of any other common file formats (I don't have a deep knowledge in that regard, though). It might be garbage data, or it might be encrypted data. Either way, I cannot help. One observation though, file_40.pdf and file_45.pdf start with identical 50+ bytes, whatever that may mean...

Comment: **@mkl** - did you solve the issue? I have a similar problem. 2 SQL IMAGE datatype columns with HEX data. first column has 65535 characters (similar to your case) and the 2nd column is variable in length. how to get the pdf out of this.

Comment: @SaiAbhiramInapala As mentioned in the answer, if the PDFs are cut off at 65535, then they essentially are lost (you may be able to partially reconstruct them but getting them back completely is unlikely).

Comment: **@mkl** - I resolved my issue. I thought they were all pdf files but turns out pdfs are converted into .RAR files and saved into the image column. So, when I export, I used .RAR as query out filetype and once the RAR files are extracted the pdf files can be extracted from it using WinRAR.